# child div are coming below each other even after using inline-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a div with has 100% as it's width. I want to place 3 more div inside it next to each other with same height as parent's height.

But due to some unknown issues I am not able to place it next to each other.

It's is flowing as `display:block` even through I have given `display:inline-block`.

What am I doing wrong here?

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/25brcg9x/)

Comment: You can set float left for all the `col` elements.
https://jsfiddle.net/25brcg9x/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/25brcg9x/2/ add inline-block for #col1, #col2 and #col3

Comment: Why do I have to float it? Can you please explain?

Comment: By using float you allow other elements to 'flow' around the element you've floated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's is flowing as display:block even through I have given display:inline-block.

There are a couple of things you can do.
Either float each element, you want on the same line, to the left or add `display:inline-block;`.

Just noticed that you have given `display:inline-block;` to the parent element not to the child elements. This is why it wasn't working for you.

Float left:
https://jsfiddle.net/25brcg9x/1/

Display inline-block:
https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/25brcg9x/2/

Comment: You can put `display` on the parent, it just applies to all children.

Comment: @Zekrom_Vale if you specify in the CSS that all the children of that element should inherit them, then yes. Otherwise `<div>` elements have a default of block display.

Comment: @Zekrom_Vale If you check the display of the child divs, in the link you've just sent, you'll notice that they still have `display: block`. The difference is that they have a fixed width and height and the parent has `display: flex`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex` and use the same margin-right and left for all all children of `div.col-12` or `#aboutUsForm`.  The following is a working example of this

```css
#aboutUsForm {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.col-12 div {
    margin:0 10%;
    width:15%
}

#col1 {
    background-color: black;
}

#col2 {
    background-color: green;
}

#col3 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-12 " id="aboutUsForm">
                <div id="col1"></div>
                <div id="col2"></div>
                <div id="col3"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to child divs or float them. Currently, they are block level elements hence they are coming in next line.

Answer (score 0):

The children of your #aboutUsForm need to also be display: inline-block. I think you are mistakenly thinking that the children would inherit this from the parent, but that is not the way it works.

Also your #aboutUsForm doesn't need to be the inline-block unless it is a main column and it's children are going to be sub columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this selector in css:

```
.parent > * {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

'*' means all elements